# The Django admin site

Tags: python, django

I start the development server and explore it. When I open the Web browser and go to “/admin/” on my local domain, http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/.I face this screen:
[image: 1]

Comment: Hi can you please show some example of code and what your doing

Comment: Also add the full output from the console.

Comment: Wait, isn't Django running on port 8080 by default?

Comment: @KlausD. No. It runs on 8000 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate all such as db or session, etc..?

```
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Check port or open another port
ex:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open cmd and enter your project path
And then enter the following commands in cmd
Note: If you have venv, activate it beforehand

```
python ./manage.py migrate
python ./manage.py runserver
```